# How can I combine my two queries into 1?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So I have:

```
SELECT
  od.PartNo,
  CAST(od.PartDesc AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS [PartDesc],
  MAX(CAST(t.TicketDate AS DATETIME)) AS [EndDate]
FROM TimeTicketDet t JOIN OrderDet od ON t.JobNo = od.JobNo
  JOIN OrderRouting r ON t.JobNo = r.JobNo
WHERE t.WorkCntr = 500
  AND r.Status = 'Finished'
GROUP BY od.PartNo, CAST(od.PartDesc AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
ORDER BY MIN(CAST(t.TicketDate AS DATETIME)) DESC
```

and

```
SELECT
  od.PartNo,
  CAST(od.PartDesc AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS [PartDesc],
  MIN(CAST(t.TicketDate AS DATETIME)) AS [StartDate]
FROM TimeTicketDet t JOIN OrderDet od ON t.JobNo = od.JobNo
  JOIN OrderRouting r ON t.JobNo = r.JobNo
WHERE t.WorkCntr = 100
GROUP BY od.PartNo, CAST(od.PartDesc AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
ORDER BY MIN(CAST(t.TicketDate AS DATETIME)) DESC
```

I need the MIN and MAX columns to be in 1 query, but because I'm referring to 2 different workcenters in the WHERE clause, I'm not sure how to go about it.  I tried this:

```
SELECT
  od.PartNo,
  CAST(od.PartDesc AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS [PartDesc],
    (SELECT
       MIN(CAST(t.TicketDate AS DATETIME)) AS [StartDate]
     FROM TimeTicketDet t JOIN OrderDet od ON t.JobNo = od.JobNo
       JOIN OrderRouting r ON t.JobNo = r.JobNo
     WHERE t.WorkCntr = 100
     GROUP BY od.PartNo
     ),
  MAX(CAST(t.TicketDate AS DATETIME)) AS [EndDate]
FROM TimeTicketDet t JOIN OrderDet od ON t.JobNo = od.JobNo
  JOIN OrderRouting r ON t.JobNo = r.JobNo
WHERE t.WorkCntr = 500
  AND r.Status = 'Finished'
GROUP BY od.PartNo, CAST(od.PartDesc AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
ORDER BY MIN(CAST(t.TicketDate AS DATETIME)) DESC
```

and that almost worked, except that the MIN column is just the first date in the system, it doesn't relate to the PartNo/Workcenter, so I'm stuck.  I'm not sure if I'm close or if I'm supposed to use something else like a CTE

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you talking about a union or just some kind of "simplification"?

Comment: `union` to remove duplicates `union all` to allow duplicates

Comment: I didn't even think about UNION.  Basically table 1 returns like 6k rows, table 2 returns like 7k rows.  Need to combine where PartNo matches both tables, so in the end, I want PartNo, PartDesc, StartDate (for WC 100), EndDate (for WC 500 and Status Finished) all in 1, 6k row table

Comment: You can do this in one query if you use case statements to decide what is fed into the MIN and MAX functions

Comment: Yeah, I think I've got the answer for that down below.

Comment: I'm curious why you're casting to `nvarchar(max)`.

Comment: It has something to do with PartDesc, I get this error if I don't cast "The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted the start and end as separate columns then a `case` expression would allow you to pick out the appropriate values after changing the `where` conditions to allow both sets of the rows through. If the desired start date is always earlier than final end date, as I imagine it might, you probably don't even need to be that fancy. You did mention having more rows in the second result so I'm not sure where that comes from and it might change the logic a bit.

That being the case it's primarily a matter of using `OR`.

```
SELECT
  od.PartNo,
  MIN(CAST(od.PartDesc AS NVARCHAR(MAX))) AS PartDesc,
  MIN(CASE WHEN t.WorkCntr  = 100 THEN CAST(t.TicketDate AS DATETIME) END)) AS StartDate,
  MAX(CASE WHEN t.WorkCntr <> 100 THEN CAST(t.TicketDate AS DATETIME) END)) AS EndDate
FROM
    TimeTicketDet t
    INNER JOIN OrderDet od ON t.JobNo = od.JobNo
    INNER JOIN OrderRouting r ON t.JobNo = r.JobNo
WHERE t.WorkCntr = 100 OR t.WorkCntr = 500 AND r.Status = 'Finished'
GROUP BY od.PartNo
ORDER BY PartDesc DESC;
```

Note: I picked that end date condition because they are opposites of each other and to me it more visibly indicates what's going on.

By the way you could have gotten your subquery to work had you correlated it:

```
...
(
    SELECT MIN(CAST(t.TicketDate AS DATETIME))
    FROM OrderDet od2 INNER JOIN TimeTicketDet t
        ON t.JobNo = od2.JobNo
    WHERE t.WorkCntr = 100 AND od2.PartDesc = od.PartDesc
) AS StartDate
...
```

Comment: Why <> 100 instead of = 500 in the MAX(CASE()) column?

Comment: Well technically you could play safe and repeat the entire second condition. Why/why not do that too? Seemed to me those were noticeable as opposites just at a glance especially once there's potential for more than just two codes involved. As it is the whole `case` is probably unnecessary anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your help, working great.  Also appreciate the additional subquery comment

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the 2 queries, just `JOIN` them.  You can `LEFT/RIGHT JOIN` if they don't have the same number of records.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        od.PartNo,
        CAST(od.PartDesc AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS [PartDesc],
        MAX(CAST(t.TicketDate AS DATETIME)) AS [EndDate]
    FROM TimeTicketDet t JOIN OrderDet od ON t.JobNo = od.JobNo
    JOIN OrderRouting r ON t.JobNo = r.JobNo
    WHERE t.WorkCntr = 500 AND r.Status = 'Finished'
    GROUP BY od.PartNo, CAST(od.PartDesc AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
) a
JOIN (
    SELECT
        od.PartNo,
        CAST(od.PartDesc AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS [PartDesc],
        MIN(CAST(t.TicketDate AS DATETIME)) AS [StartDate]
    FROM TimeTicketDet t JOIN OrderDet od ON t.JobNo = od.JobNo
    JOIN OrderRouting r ON t.JobNo = r.JobNo
    WHERE t.WorkCntr = 100
    GROUP BY od.PartNo, CAST(od.PartDesc AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
) b ON b.PartNo = a.PartNo
```

Comment: The other answer before you worked fine, but this one is quite different so I'll definitely play around with it.  Thank you

Comment: @user1452574 Answer by @shawnt00 is definitely more efficient.  It just uses one `GROUP BY`.  I basically made use of the 2 queries that you have created, and joined it.